# Rotating parent object without rotating child objects that are instantiated

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a parent object rotate based on another objects rotation but the childs that are instantiated rotate too which I don't want, how can if fix this. This is my code and the example

```
public GameObject prefab;
public GameObject solarPanelTransparent;
public GameObject preview;
public GameObject panel;
public int xAmount = 3;
public int yAmount = 3;
public float scale = 1;
public GameObject quat;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        // if(panel.transform.childCount>0)
        //     Destroy(panel.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
        panel.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        panel.transform.position = transform.position;
        for (int i =0; i < yAmount; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(prefab, transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, i*1.2f), Quaternion.identity, panel.transform);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < xAmount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < yAmount; j++)
            {
                Instantiate(prefab, transform.position + new Vector3((i * 0.7f), 0, j*1.2f), Quaternion.identity, panel.transform);

            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < xAmount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < yAmount; j++)
            {
               Instantiate(prefab, transform.position - new Vector3((i * 0.7f), 0, -j*1.2f), Quaternion.identity, panel.transform);
            }
        }
        panel.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);  
    }
    panel.transform.rotation = quat.transform.rotation;
    
}
```

The first image is the parent object with the same rotation as the quad, the second image is the child object which the rotation is changed, but I don't want that.

[image: This is the parent object with the same rotation as the quad]

[image: This is the child object which the rotation is changed, but I don't want that]

Comment: Both images show exactly the same transforms, the second just shows one of the child objects selected.

Comment: They are different if you look at the values, the child objects are rotated so that lay flat like when you would instantiate them alone without rotation. I don't know why it rotates the child objects like that.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following here, are you saying that when you rotate the parents that the children also rotate independently? If you change the transform of the parent, the children should also transform relative to the parent coords. e.g. if the children are 0,0,0 in rotation, if you rotate the parent to 50,0,0 the children's local rotation should still be 0,0,0 but their relative (world) rotation would be 50,0,0. Are you saying this isn't happening and that the children are independently rotating? If so, stop using `panel.transform` and use a zero transform when instantiating.

Comment: Yes the children are rotating independently against the parent which is weird, shouldn't they stay with a local rotation of (0,0,0)? I will try with a zero transform but think I've already done that

Comment: the point of child objects is that transformations that are applied to the parent also apply to the child. If you don't want that you have 2 choices. 1. don't make it a child object or 2. take the transformation you applied to the parent and apply the negative transformation to the children

Comment: The problem is that I need to rotate the whole object as a unit all aligned which each other, so they need to be parented to make it rotate with that parent object. each time I try to set the parent the localrotation changes.

Comment: oh now i see, you could `var child = Instantiate(....)` and `child.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity` , but actually that's curious. not 100% sure how instantiate is implemented, but if it sets the parent after location and rotation it will add the negative rotation/position of the parent to the child.

Comment: Actually just looking it all looks ok - you are passing `Quarternion.identity` so the children should be 0,0,0 in terms of rotation, but they should take the parent's rotation in world space... if you set the parent to rotate slowly in your update, do the panels rotate as a flat "plane" or does each one also rotate as the parent rotates making the panel "open up"? I believe the editor is supposed to show local transform (you need a plugin to show world coords/rotation - you don't have one do you?).. bit baffling tbh.. (unless the above comment from nka is true)

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone, I didn't think that there were that many implementations of instantiate. I changed that a bit but I think the key was to set the parent eulerangles to vector3.zero before instantiating.

Comment: Will post the solution below

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            // if(panel.transform.childCount>0)
            //     Destroy(panel.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
            panel.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            panel.transform.position = transform.position;
            panel.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
            GameObject obj;
            for (int i =0; i < yAmount; i++)
            {
               obj = Instantiate(prefab, panel.transform);
               obj.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, i*1.2f);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < xAmount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < yAmount; j++)
                {
                   obj= Instantiate(prefab, panel.transform);
                    obj.transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3((i * 0.7f), 0, j*1.2f);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < xAmount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < yAmount; j++)
                {
                   obj = Instantiate(prefab, panel.transform);
                   obj.transform.position = transform.position - new Vector3((i * 0.7f), 0, -j*1.2f);

                }
            }
            panel.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);  
        }
        panel.transform.eulerAngles = quat.transform.eulerAngles;
        
    }
```